# /cmd_vel robot keeps moving

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am using the program showed in this tutorial :

pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Using the robot base controllers to drive the robot

the only difference is that instead of using the topic /base_controller/command I used the /cmd_vel because is the only suscribed topics on the youbot_oodl_driver.launch

the thing is that after sending the command to move forward the robot should stop because is not receiving more commands. Nevertheless this does not happen and the robot keeps moving forward .

On the other hand if I used the topic /base_controller/command the robot stops.

Could somebody help me please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67148//cmd_vel-robot-keeps-moving/) by [prinho](https://answers.ros.org/users/5393/prinho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-07-11**:
What package are you using for interfacing your robot?? Is ur robot is subscribed to both "cmd_vel" and  "/base_controller/command" for input velocity??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Timing out after no new messages are received is a design decision of whatever node is subscribing to the messages.  It's a common one, and good for safety, but is not required.  You should look into whatever node is receiving the topic.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1